# Power Query file path from cell value

Tags: excel, filepath, powerquery

I have, in my excel workbook, a Table called ResultsTable, in that table there is a file path
[image]

> C:\Users\XXXX\OneDrive - WORK\Digital
>   Soil\Data\Results

I have Query that should get all excel files from the folder and transform the data into something usefull looking like this:

```
let
    Source = Folder.Files("ResultsTable"),
    #"Filtered Hidden Files1" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Attributes]?[Hidden]? <> true),
    #"Invoke Custom Function1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Hidden Files1", "Transform File from Analyseresultater", each #"Transform File from Analyseresultater"([Content])),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Invoke Custom Function1", {"Name", "Source.Name"}),
    #"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Renamed Columns1", {"Source.Name", "Transform File from Analyseresultater"}),
    #"Expanded Table Column1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns1", "Transform File from Analyseresultater", Table.ColumnNames(#"Transform File from Analyseresultater"(#"Sample File"))),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Expanded Table Column1",{"Key", "Attribute", "Value"})
in
    #"Removed Other Columns"
```

But I get the error

> DataFormat.Error: The supplied folder path must be a valid absolute
>   path. Details:
>       ResultsTable

I hope someone can help me get through this error :)

EDIT: Added screenshot of how my sheet with tables are set up

Comment: What's the structure of `Results Table` ? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the code like,

```
let
    FilePath = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="ResultsTable"]}[Content][Path to results]{0},
    Source = Folder.Files(FilePath),
```

In the original code, `Folder.Files()` was receiving the literal text "ResultsTable", not the cell value in ResultsTable. You need to first pick the cell value with `Excel.CurrentWorkbook()`, and then pass it to `Folder.Files()`.